# Neet help in creating the parent/child structure in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML :

I'm trying to send the `<p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>` to a Jquery function, upon clicking on the Edit button. I need help in completing the below structure :

```
Comment = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1];
```

```html
<div class=" p-3 border-top border-bottom bg-light">
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center osahan-post-header">
    <div class="dropdown-list-image mr-3 mb-auto"><img class="rounded-circle" src="img/p8.png" alt=""></div>
    <div class="mr-1">
      <div class="text-truncate h6 mb-3">{{ $comment->user->first_name }} {{ $comment->user->last_name }}</div>
      <p>{{ $comment->comment }}</p>
    </div>
    <span class="ml-auto mb-auto">
      <div class="text-right text-muted pt-1 small">{{ $comment->created_at}}</div>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="post" align="right" data-postid="{{ $comment->id }}">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" id="eid">Edit</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and change the templating for actual HTML content. What event will trigger the code you need?

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You cannot have a div inside a span

Comment: I'm editing in a ready made template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would fix your invalid HTML (as already mentioned in a comment, a `<div>` can't be inside a `<span>`), you could get the comment as follows:

```
document.getElementById("eid").onclick = function(e) {
  let comment = e.target.closest(".p-3").getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML;
  console.log(comment);
};
```

or, if you would use jQuery:

```
 $("#eid").on("click", function(){
    let comment = $(this).closest(".p-3").find("p").text();
    console.log(comment);
 });
```

Comment: @AbdallahSakre Glad I was able to help :)